# установка с помощью apt Android-studio, Linux. dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива

Tags: linux, android-studio, apt-get

Первый раз устанавливал с помощью скачивания архива, распаковки и запуска исполняемого файла. Была туча ошибок, снес `OS` и пробую установить с помощью `apt`

Установил `Oracle java8` вроде как, если подскажете как проверить версию, буду признателен, далее сделал следующие команды:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt install android-studio
```

После чего получаю вывод консоли:

> dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb (--unpack):
>   подпроцесс новый сценарий pre-installation возвратил код ошибки 8

При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:

> /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

[image: окно консоли]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Comment: я так делал в прошлый раз. После чего была туча ошибок. Через менеджер пакетов никак не установить ?

Comment: Что-то пошло не так, из скрина ошибка: Вы ломитесь на гугл и получаете ошибку 404, контент не найден, хочется пошутить, что Вас забанили в гугле, но я понимаю, что это не смешно :) Какая ось? 16 ubuntu?

Comment: elementaryOS Loki, не знаю даже, 3 дня с android studio танцую. пробую на чистую OS сейчас поставить старым способом, потому что проблему в apt не могу решить

Comment: А какие характеристики машины? Вы бы поставили обычную `ubuntu` меньше проблем было бы, а если машина слабая, то вы должны понимать, студия тоже не мало ресурсов хавает

Comment: Машина ее и на Windows 10 тянула. Было не совсем комфортно, но тянула, из-за чего решил поставить Linux второй системой и в будущем полностью перейти, если понравится. А дистрибутив выбирал исходя из оформления )

Если по теме: сейчас все установилось, AVD создал, но не может ее стартануть. Повисела надпись "Waiting for target device...", потом закрылось и ничего не произошло. Но для этого уже, наверно, другую тему стартовать ?

Comment: Я Вам очень советую `ubuntu` по причине того, что этот дистрибутив поддерживается и регулярно обновляется, на него есть куча софта и ставиться он парой команд

Comment: Последовал вашему совету, осталась та же ошибка с waiting for device

Comment: Гуглите, на ubuntu ставиться замечательно, ставил на разных машинах, никогда небыло проблем, не получится - создавайте новый вопрос с подробными логами

Comment: @IgorSergeevich можно как-то с вами связаться ? вроде бы исправил ошибку, как мне кажется, сейчас финишная прямая до запуска. Можно как-то с вами связаться через какую-либо соц-сеть или мессенджер ?

Comment: у меня в профиле есть ссыль на facebook

Answer (score 1):

Установка пакетов из не оффициальных репозиториев это вечная война с зависимостями...
Для приложений на Java дестрибутив не критичен, главное наличие совместимой JVM/

Прверте версию java:

```
~$ java -version
```

Установите Oracle Java:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Скачайте (проверте наличие версии сами) напрямую android-studio, распакуйте и пользуйтесь осторожно!:

```
~$ wget https://dl.google.com/android/studio/install/0.3.2/android-studio-bundle-132.893413-linux.tgz
~$ tar xzf android-*linux.tgz
```

- https://www.lifewire.com/install-android-studio-for-linux-4056779
- https://gist.github.com/bmc08gt/8077443

p.s. debian, ubuntu, elementary, linux mint (используем на работе ubuntu для станций) имеют совместные репозитории.

fedora linux (пользуюсь дома 5 лет) имеет самые последние сборки и обновления